# Raycast is firing just one ray Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, raycasting

I'm actually working on a word search like game.

But i'm having issues when i want to select instantiate gameObjects on a grid.

as i saw on unity doc, i used raycast to check which collider has been hit, and do some logic.

So i wrote this:

```
void Update(){

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray;
        RaycastHit hit;
        GameObject current;

        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "tile")
            {
                //Do some logic
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, i used this:

```
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 50;
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);
```

to display raycasts when i run the game.

So when i click with my mouse, a single ray is fired.

Normally it should fire a lot more. But i don't know why it's shooting just one ray.

Also,

> Input.mousePosition

does not seem to work. the ray just fires at the center of my screen.

How can i fix that? Is there other method than raycast?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You just want to detect which object is clicked? What type of object is this(2D sprite, 3D mesh or UI)?

Comment: I want to detect when the user touch the screen to select some letters. To make a word, the player need to maintain the touch and move is finger to other letters. Letters are UI elements.

Comment: And those letters are the objects you are raycasting? Is this a Text or Image component?

Comment: Yes, i cast ray from the camera, and normally when it hits a letter, it should do something, but the raycast just fires one ray, and stop after that. i don't have any error on my log.

Comment: `Physics.Raycast` is used on 2D or 3D objects not UI's.  Check #1 from the duplicate on ways to detect clicks on UI components. Also, please don't attach a collider to a UI component

Comment: So, how could i detect a moving finger on a UI element?

Comment: That would be `OnDrag` in this case. See the duplicate for how to use that.

Comment: Aside of that programmer is right about UI elements, what appears to be only one ray firing is actually you drawing the wrong thing. To properly draw your ray use `Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10f, Color.green);` (its multiplied by 10, because the direction is normalized and not the distance to the hit, the number is arbitrary) - currently you draw a "ray" from the gameobject holding your scripts position along its forward axis, not the ray you created.

Comment: @yes Thanks, after i change what you said, i can see the direction, but it still fires just one ray when i old my mouse button down.

Comment: There is an overload with a 4th argument for `Debug.DrawRay` its how long the ray is visible (in seconds), by default its drawn for only one frame and thats way to short to see. Also `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` only is true in the frame you pressed the button - maybe you want `Input.GetMouseButton` instead? Its true for as long as the button is pressed. 
 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html